# How to check if qt is build with specific configuration

Tags: linux, qt, qt5

I am following the guide [here](https://www.ics.com/blog/whats-new-qt-560-logging-syslog-and-journald) to log my debug/info messages in `journald`.

The guide states that the qt must be compiled with either ofconfiguration:

```
  Logging backends:
    journald ............... yes
```

I do not get any output in the journald, so I assume that configuration is missing.

How can I check that the current qt that is in my system configured with that option?

Answer (score 2):

As the Qt documentation you linked says,

> *To enable the syslog or journald logging support in Qt 5.6.0 or later, you need to configure it into Qt.* **They default to being disabled**, *so you need to explicitly use the -journald or -syslog options when running the configure script.*

So you **MUST** recompile Qt from sources in order to get this functionality, or find a pre-built version with these options enabled - I would say "good luck" for this, in particular on Linux.

You can check [this page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html) for starting a Qt rebuild.

Comment: well thanks for the hint. Do you know is there a way to check if my qt was built using those options?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. This isn't the only lack in Qt, you know... :(( I think that there is nothing outside the test suite, the one you have to run (if you're serious!) after a build, in order to check that everything is OK. I've checked in my Qt binary folder, and I didn't found anything (immediately visible) to get this information: `qmake -v`, `qmake -query` or `qtdiag` don't seem to show this kind of information.